# Identify a 4500 model

Tags: cisco

I have a 45xx model and want to identify a specific IOS version for it.
Trouble is I cannot figure what Platform is from the following:

- CAT4500-SUP2-PLUS
- CAT4500-SUP2-PLUS-TS
- CAT4500-SUP3
- CAT4500-SUP4
- CAT4500-SUP5
- CAT4948

Both show version and show platform tell me that this is a 4507 still how can I guess from the options above?

```
show module           
Chassis Type : WS-C4507R

Power consumed by backplane : 40 Watts

Mod Ports Card Type                              Model              Serial No.
---+-----+--------------------------------------+------------------+-----------
 1     2  Supervisor IV 1000BaseX (GBIC)         WS-X4515           JAE09065N62 
 2     2  Supervisor IV 1000BaseX (GBIC)         WS-X4515           JAE10223LPP 
 3    48  10/100BaseTX (RJ45)                    WS-X4148-RJ        JAE09044J58 
 4    48  10/100BaseTX (RJ45)                    WS-X4148-RJ        JAE08041PL0 
 5    48  10/100BaseTX (RJ45)V                   WS-X4148-RJ45V     JAE10254S3T 
 6    48  10/100BaseTX (RJ45)                    WS-X4148-RJ        JAE08041QL8 
 7    48  10/100BaseTX (RJ45)V                   WS-X4148-RJ45V     JAE1003TZ0Q 

 M MAC addresses                    Hw  Fw           Sw               Status
--+--------------------------------+---+------------+----------------+---------
 1 0012.daf6.c980 to 0012.daf6.c981 4.0 12.2(20r)EW1 12.2(25)EWA4     Ok       
 2 0012.daf6.c982 to 0012.daf6.c983 5.0 12.2(20r)EW1 12.2(25)EWA4,    Ok       
 3 0012.80c1.5a20 to 0012.80c1.5a4f 3.1                               Ok       
 4 000e.d718.5750 to 000e.d718.577f 3.1                               Ok       
 5 0018.180f.c800 to 0018.180f.c82f 3.0                               Ok       
 6 000e.d716.c4d0 to 000e.d716.c4ff 3.1                               Ok       
 7 0016.461d.29f0 to 0016.461d.2a1f 2.9                               Ok       

Mod  Redundancy role     Redundancy mode     Redundancy status
----+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------
 1   Active Supervisor   SSO                 Active             
 2   Standby Supervisor  SSO                 Standby hot        

Also show  version output:

show ver
Cisco IOS Software, Catalyst 4000 L3 Switch Software (cat4000-I9S-M), Version 12.2(25)EWA4, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2005 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Fri 23-Sep-05 13:31 by ssearch
Image text-base: 0x10000000, data-base: 0x114DFF08

ROM: 12.2(20r)EW1
Dagobah Revision 95, Swamp Revision 29

4507-01 uptime is 2 years, 19 weeks, 1 day, 8 hours, 57 minutes
Uptime for this control processor is 2 years, 19 weeks, 1 day, 9 hours, 25 minutes
System returned to ROM by power-on
System restarted at 09:08:10 EEST Sat Jul 16 2011
System image file is "bootflash:cat4000-i9s-mz.122-25.EWA4.bin"

cisco WS-C4507R (MPC8245) processor (revision 7) with 524288K bytes of memory.
Processor board ID FOX090105QF
MPC8245 CPU at 333Mhz, Supervisor IV
Last reset from PowerUp
3 Virtual Ethernet interfaces
240 FastEthernet interfaces
4 Gigabit Ethernet interfaces
403K bytes of non-volatile configuration memory.

Configuration register is 0x2
```

Comment: the relevant information is the supervisor version. do a "sho ver | in sup|Sup"

Comment: just added show version output

Comment: Also, it's worth noting the IOS version currently running is not SUP specific (there's no supX in the file name.) So, it's likely any of those choices will take you to the same files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you have:

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/switches/ps5718/ps4324/product_data_sheet0900aecd8035cf2b.html

This is where you will download your IOS from:

http://software.cisco.com/download/type.html?mdfid=277241602&flowid=2433

Comment: So based on this would be CAT4500-SUP4.

Comment: yes, "Processor board ID FOX090105QF MPC8245 CPU at 333Mhz, Supervisor IV"  That's why doing the command I listed previously would have filtered your output down.